# How to fix etcd within a kuberentes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have a bare-metal (kubeadm) kubernetes cluster that's really unstable, and I traced it back to an etcd issue.

From the etcd pod's description I get:

```
Image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
Liveness: ... #success=1 #failure=8
Startup:  ... #success=1 #failure=24
```

In the logs startup sequence seems fine (compared to another cluster), then I get a lot of warnings:

```
etcdserver: [...] request ... took too long to execute
```

But I don't think it's hardware related because `etcd_disk_backend_commit_duration_seconds` 99th percentile is at 16ms which is fine according to the [FAQ](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/#what-does-the-etcd-warning-apply-entries-took-too-long-mean).

Anyways, this goes on for a few minutes, and then I guess this causes the restart:

```
etcdserver/api/etcdhttp: /health error; QGET failed etcdserver: request timed out (status code 503)
```

Any idea what further steps I can take to diagnose the issue and fix etcd ?

Comment: Did you see this [issue](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/11809)? Is it similar to yours?

Comment: Well it has some similarities, but in the issue you mention the timeouts start just after startup wheras in my case it starts after a few minutes of uptime. Also it isn't clear if there is a crash in the other issue, whereas for me there is for sure. But I'll continue to look into disk performance until I get a better idea...

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Can you provide steps how exactly did you set up the cluster?

Comment: Hello @Antoine. Any updates?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get help on github and resolve the issue: https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/13373. I think at some point my node changed its private IP because of hardware issues, and upon upgrading etcd it caused configuration issues. Fix was to dump+restore etcd data.